# How to add Inbound Endpoint to a Composite Application Project in WSO2 developer studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I created an inbound endpoint xml file in WSO2 ESB project, but cannot add the project to a Composite Application Project. So, it cannot be deployed to WSO2 ESB server as a CAR package. It seems that CAR package needs at least an api or a proxy, but it is not necessary if I just want an inbound endpoint. Can anyone help to case please?

Comment: What is the WSO2 ESB version you are using?

Comment: I tried ESB 4.9.0, 5.0.0 and also EI 6.1.1, and Developer Studio Kernel Version 4.1.0.201607150652.